# При копировании файлов в каталоге появляется ошибка на не существование пути к каталогу или самого файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа должна копировать все файлы с текущего каталога и всех подкаталогов.

При запуске программа отработала и скопировала 42 из 299 файлов и выдала следующую ошибку:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-40d66524ed3e> in <module>()

----> 1 copy_files(r'C:\Users\Dmytro\Desktop\map')

<ipython-input-1-fbaa373faa32> in copy_files(folder)

      7     for currentFolder, subFolders, fileNames in os.walk(folder):
      8         for i in fileNames:
----> 9             shutil.copy(currentFolder+'\\'+i, 
r'C:\Users\Dmytro\Desktop\Folder')

~\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copy(src, dst, follow_symlinks)

    239     if os.path.isdir(dst):
    240         dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
--> 241     copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)

    242     copymode(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    243     return dst

~\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)

    118         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    119     else:
--> 120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Dmytro\\Desktop\\map\\LOFT APARTMENT -share by QKK\\qwe]\\LOFT APARTMENT LIVINGROOM-by QKK\\map\\30.5.17\\30.05.17\\SCAN CRN sua\\chua loc 1.9\\New folder (6)\\New folder\\20150702_Livingroom_Corona_4pixosGIFTscene\\20150120 Interior Design\\MAX\\MAP\\GlassEtchings.jpg'
```

Хотя сам файл и каталог существуют, иначе как модуль walk узнал о них.

Решил перед копированием сделать проверку на существование каталога и файла и о чудо, программа отработала без ошибок, но скопировла 255/299 файлов, как так и почему некоторые каталоги и файлы не видит?

Сама программа:

```
import shutil

import os



def copy_files(folder):

    '''Copy all files in current Folder and sub Folder'''
    for currentFolder, subFolders, fileNames in os.walk(folder):
        for i in fileNames:
            if os.path.isdir(currentFolder) and os.path.isfile(currentFolder+'\\'+i):
                shutil.copy(currentFolder+'\\'+i, r'C:\Users\Dmytro\Desktop\Folder')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: 260 байтов полного имени - перебор походу.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation

Очень похоже что у вас слишком длинный путь.

Comment: Все верно, слишком длинный путь.
Спасибо